# AngularJS Service http

Tags: html, angularjs, api

Tenho um service no angular e queria fazer um forEach para recuperar o valor do usuario, para autenticar o login

Meu service:

```
.service('usuariosService', function ($rootScope, $location,$http) {

    this.validaLogin = function(user){
        var usuarios = [];
$http.get('api/user').then(function(resultado){
              usuarios = resultado.data;
          });

        angular.forEach(usuarios, function(value, index){            
                if(value.nome == user.username){
                    $rootScope.usuarioLogado = value;
                }else{
                    console.log('Não é igual');
                }
            })
    }
})
```

Porém não consigo fazer esse forEach, nunca consigo comprar os valores, Não sei se é o retorno da api, ou o value.nome não está recebendo nenhum valor.

meu json retorna isso:

```
[{ "nome" : "teste", "password" : "teste" },
 { "nome" : "teste1", "password" : "teste1" }];
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Tenta pegar só o resultado e não resultado.data, da um console.log(resultado); e veja a saida.

Comment: Dei um console log fora do bloco $http e veio vazio :( " [] " Dentro do bloco $http veio assim: Object {data: Array[1], status: 200, config: Object}

Comment: Cara tá retornando ok, qual é o conteúdo de resultado.data? Tem que os dados ali. E é isso mesmo tem que executar isso no callback do http.get, você chegou a ver o conteúdo de "data" dentro "resultado"? se não for ali, você tem que ver o que está chegando no parâmetro da função aquele "user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o seu forEach dentro do callback `.then(function(resultado){})`

Quando é chamado o `angular.forEach`, não necessariamente o valor de `usuarios` será o retorno da requisição $http, porém dentro do callback é garantido esse valor.

```
 .service('usuariosService', function($rootScope, $location, $http) {
    this.validaLogin = function(user) {
      $http.get('api/user').then(function(resultado) {

        angular.forEach(resultado.data, function(value, index) {
         if (value.nome == user.username) {
           $rootScope.usuarioLogado = value;
         }else {
            console.log('Não é igual');
         }
      })
    });
  }
})
```

Recomendo também alterar o código para evitar problemas de minificação:

```
.service('usuariosService', usuariosService);

usuariosService.$inject = ['$rootScope','$location','$http'];    

function usuariosService($rootScope, $location, $http) {
    this.validaLogin = function(user) {
      $http.get('api/user').then(function(resultado) {

        angular.forEach(resultado.data, function(value, index) {
         if (value.nome == user.username) {
           $rootScope.usuarioLogado = value;
         }else {
            console.log('Não é igual');
         }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification